# schedule a task to run every day within a time range?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-task-scheduler

How do I schedule a task to run once any time within a time range?

and also, just once in a day without specifying a time?

can windows task scheduler do it?

and specifically, if my computer is off or on standby or hibernation at the time I want it to run it when it is on if it hasn't been run that day and the time has passed.

I see an option to wake it to run the task , but could I then put it back to sleep? And i'd like to be able to as mentioned.. let it run when the computer is back on.

Comment: I understand scheduling a missed task is possible in vista and 7 's ms windows task scheduler, but not xp's ms windows task scheduler. i know xp's has a wakeup option though , but not quite what I want. There may be an alternative to windows task scheduler though that does what I want. so great if anybody knows of one that does what I want

Answer (score 1):

This sort of functionality is available in Vista and Windows 7, but not on Windows XP unfortunately.

Have a look at `cron` under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), or the [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) project on SourceForge.

Alternatively, check out this (unconfirmed) list from [this page](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/best-task-scheduler-t2976893.html):

- [Freebyte Task Scheduler](http://www.freebyte.com/fbtaskscheduler/)
- [Kana Reminder](http://www.kana.homeip.net/index.php?doc=reminder&page=features)
- [M2 Launcher](http://msquaredtechnologies.com/m2_products.htm)
- [nnCron LITE](http://newfreeware.com/utils/689/)
- [PowerPro](http://www.windowspowerpro.com/)
- [Smooth Program Scheduler](http://www.xemico.com/scheduler/index.html)
- [Show Stopper](http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptstopper.asp)
- [Smooth Program Scheduler](http://www.xemico.com/scheduler/)
- [System Scheduler](http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm)
- [X-ecutor](http://www.xpertdesign.de/english/sw_xecutor_info.htm)

Comment: That isn't an answer at all.  An answer would suggest an alternative

Comment: I have provided possible alternatives in an updated answer.